# Checkboxes in list show check when clicked, but isChecked() is unchanged (Android)

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes (created via custom list adapter), some of which start checked based on stored data.  When the user presses another button, I'd like to check which boxes are checked.  Right now it starts with two boxes, one of which is clicked.  When I click the checkboxes the UI changes appropriately, but when I do the "gather checked" function, it reports the original configuration, not the changed one.

The XML for the row:

```
CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Default"
android:id="@+id/cause_checkbox"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

The List adapter:
    private class CauseEntryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        List selectedCauseKeys;
        List availableCauseKeys;

```
    public CauseEntryAdapter(Context context, List<String> causeLabels, List<String> availableCauseKeys, List<String> selectedCauseKeys) {
        super(context, 0, causeLabels);
        if (selectedCauseKeys != null)
            this.selectedCauseKeys = selectedCauseKeys;
        else
            this.selectedCauseKeys = new LinkedList<>();

        this.availableCauseKeys = availableCauseKeys;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String cause = (String) getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cause_list_item, parent, false);

        }
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cause_checkbox);
        checkbox.setText(cause);
        checkbox.setChecked(selectedCauseKeys.contains(availableCauseKeys.get(position)));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The code to collect checked boxes:

```
public List<String> getCheckedCauses() {
    List<String> ret = new LinkedList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i< mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        CheckBox checkBox =  (CheckBox) mAdapter.getView(i, null, null).findViewById(R.id.cause_checkbox);
        if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
            ret.add((String) mAdapter.getItem(i));
        }
        //TODO why is this picking up preferences not the list?
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The list lives in a fragment, I invoke it with:

```
CauseListFragment causeListFragment = (CauseListFragment)  fragmentManager.getFragments().get(0);
return causeListFragment.getCheckedCauses();
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your getCheckedCauses method asks the adapter to tell him the state of checkboxed by calling the getView method, which relies on the original state you passed to the adapter.

One solution may be, in your adapter, to set a listener on the checkboxes and update the availableCauseKey list each time a check box is clicked.

EDIT: Or simpler, have a isBoxChecked() method in your adapter like this:

```
public boolean isBoxChecked(int viewId){
    View convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cause_list_item, parent, false);
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cause_checkbox);
    return checkBox.isChecked();
    }
```

Comment: 'public boolean isBoxChecked(int viewId){
        View frame = mAdapter.getView(viewId, null, null);
        View convertView = LayoutInflater.from(frame.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cause_list_item, (ViewGroup) frame.getParent(), false);
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cause_checkbox);
        return checkbox.isChecked();
    }'

returns false no matter what.

Comment: The method you mention in your comment refers to mAdapter.getView() again. Like in your first implementation. Can't you just use getContext() to get the context in your adapter? Where did you put this code? It should be in the Adapter. If that does not work, then try my first solution. Let me know how it goes.